# python startswith method

Tags: python

I'm a bit new to python and can't figure out why this is not working.
I have a variable that is something like this:

```
[u'\n                Data I want              ']
```

but I also have variables that are simply:

```
[u'                more Data I want              ']
```

I am running the variables through a loop but I need to strip all the extra stuff around the data.  I created a function to deal with this but I'm not sure why its not working(I'm not sure but I suspect \n is a special character)

```
def stripName(name):
    name = str(name)
    if name.startswith( "\n" ):
        print "starts with new line"
        name = name[5:-2]
    else:
        print "does not start with new line"
        name = name[3:-2]
    return name
```

The problem is the "if name.startswith( "\n" )" never matches..I've looked at other examples and I think I'm doing it as they are.  I even tried`if name.startswith( "\n" ) == 'True':` but that didn't work either.

Thanks in advance for any insight you guys can give.

Comment: It's not a "command" it's a "method" of a string.  Please update your question.

Comment: Hi S.Lott..I just updated it sorry about that..unlike 5 minutes ago I didn't know the difference..lol. sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
def stripName(name):
    return name[0].strip()
```

?

Comment: wow thanks..that pretty much removed major of my code.  Didn't know you could that.  Thanks Steve!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are passing in a `list` instance and then converting that into a string using `str` (in `name=str(name)`). Try `name=name[0]` instead.

Also, the code looks improperly formatted. The lines following `def` should be indented by one level.

Another thing, `startswith` is not a command. It is a *method*. Please get your terminology straight, otherwise you will end up getting very confused. A programming language like Python does not have any "commands". Instead code is made up of statements and expressions, including method calls.

Comment: Thank you MAK..makes sense..I'm still thinking like I was in my shell scripting days..lol.  Thank you for your tips and help! Have an awesome day!

Answer (score 1):

If name is `[u'\n   data  ']`, then `str(name)` includes the square brackets. You should write

```
name = name[0]
```